# Optimal control problem with Hamiltonian linear in control

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Let's consider the following deterministic optimal control problem, where $c(t)$ is the control, and $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the state variables:
\begin{align}
J(t) = \inf_{c(t)} \ &\int_0^\infty e^{-\delta u} \left( x^2(u) + \lambda y^2(u) \right) du 
\end{align}
where the dynamics for the states are:
\begin{align}
x'(t) &= c(t) - y(t) - a \\
y'(t) &= \delta y(t) - b x(t)
\end{align}
where $\lambda > 0$, $a>0$ and $b>0$ are constants, $x(0)=x_0$, and the transversality $\lim_{T \to \infty} E_t [e^{-\delta T} y(T)]=0$ condition holds. Notice that the control impacts the dynamics of $x$ directly, and those of $y$ indirectly by affecting $x$.

**Solution**

First, I write the Hamiltonian:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H} = x^2(t) + \lambda y^2(t) + J_{x}(t) ( c(t) - y(t) - a ) + J_{y}(t) \left( \delta y(t) - b x(t) \right) 
\end{align}
where $J_{x}(t)$ and $J_{y}(t)$ denote the derivatives of the value function with respect to the states (i.e. the co-state variables).

Next, I write the optimality conditions:
\begin{align}
0 = \mathcal{H}_{c}(t) &\rightarrow 0 = J_{x}(t) \nonumber \\
0 = \mathcal{H}_{x}(t) + J_{x}'(t) - \delta J_{x}(t) &\rightarrow 0 = 2 x(t) - J_{y}(t) b \nonumber \\
0 = \mathcal{H}_{y}(t) + J_{y}'(t) - \delta J_{y}(t) &\rightarrow 0 = 2 \lambda y(t) + J_{y}'(t) \nonumber 
\end{align}
Differentiating the second condition:
\begin{align}
0 = 2 x'(t) - J_{y}'(t) b \rightarrow J_{y}'(t) = \frac{2 x'(t)}{b}
\end{align}
and substituting it in the third:
\begin{align}
0 = 2 \lambda y(t) + \frac{2 x'(t)}{b} \rightarrow x'(t) = - \lambda b y(t)
\end{align}
Finally, substituting this result in the law of motion for $x$, I obtain the optimal control:
\begin{align}
c(t) = x'(t) + y(t) + a \rightarrow c(t) = (1 - \lambda b ) y(t) + a
\end{align}

**Question**

Looking at the problem, I would be tempted to say that since the Hamiltonian is linear in the control, this is a bang bang problem and $c(t) = +\infty$ when $J_x(t) > 0$ and $c(t) = -\infty$ when $J_x(t) < 0$. How are these two results consistent?

Comment: Another comment: the bang-bang principle does not apply  here because your switching function (i.e. the coefficient of $c$ in the Hamiltonian, in your notation $J_x(t)$) is identically $0$. So we cannot use the Weierstrass condition to identify the optimal control. Basically the Hamiltonian along the optimal trajectories does not explicitly depend on $c$.

Comment: Just to clarify, you said that the reason the bang-bang principle does not hold is that $H_c=J_x(t)=0$. But what is not immediately visible is that the control $c(t)$ influences $x(t)$, which in turn influences $y(t)$, although the latter is not directly affected by $c(t)$. Is this one additional reason why it does not hold?